# Dependency injection and when to use static classes

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, mef

Are static classes pretty much always frowned upon, or is there ever a good time to use them?

For example, would it make sense to implement something ubiquitous in your application like security in a static class?  You could still use property injection on the static class to change out the implementation, and if you were to use something like MEF to inject the implementation then I would think it wouldn't get in the way of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I use static classes mainly for stateless helper classes and when I want to create extension methods. I try to avoid static classes that have state because as you mention it can get in the way of the tests.

Let's say you decide to add state to a static class. To test the methods of this class that depend on its state you will have to find a way to change this state during the tests. This means that you have to:

1. Prepare the state before each test.
2. Clear the state after each test.

This means that the class will need to offer a way (by means of internal methods or internal property setters) to alter its state which can be dangerous. If you want to create immutable classes or classes that encapsulate completely their implementation details then you will not be able to test them easily (if not at all) and your test might break more often from changes to the implementation. Even with MEF it will not be easy to do this.

Of course static class sometimes offer attractive solutions for problems like logging and,as mentioned in your question, security. In these cases I would go for a `static class` that delegates all calls to a `private readonly` field. This way the class of this field can be unit tested normally. You can then test the static class in your integration tests.

By the way have a look at .NET's [design guidelines for static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It doesn't include anything relevant to your question but it includes valuable advice.